# How to fetch rows from pandas dataframe column having list filed with some value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:-

```
        50%       75%       max         IRQ         LL        Result    value

 0     12455.0   15836.0    15859.0     16701.0     3404.0      []      Failure
 1     270904.0  282640.0   370758.0    445823.0    99854.0     []      NEW
 2     1689.0    3114.0     3921.0      6102.0      2232.0  0.0 [12,2]  Others
 3    431655.0   458620.0   638670.0    753572.0    207015.0    [99]    Success
```

I want to fetch rows having result column list is not empty.

Output:-

```
        50%       75%       max         IRQ         LL        Result    value

 1     1689.0    3114.0     3921.0      6102.0      2232.0    [12,2]     Others
 2    431655.0   458620.0   638670.0    753572.0    207015.0    [99]      Success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.len`:

```
new_df = df[df["Result"].str.len().ne(0)]
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
        50%       75%       max       IRQ        LL   Result    value
2    1689.0    3114.0    3921.0    6102.0    2232.0  [12, 2]   Others
3  431655.0  458620.0  638670.0  753572.0  207015.0     [99]  Success
```

Comment: if I want to check at the same time IQR value is present in Result column list how I can achieve that.@Chris

Comment: @vishwajeetMane That's a completely different question and it's not really advised to ask question in the comment :p I would recommend you to post another question for that ;)